# jquery class selector runs event more than ones on multiples tries

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Lets save I have a couple of divs with anchor tags in them that have the same class as such

```
<div id="div1">
<input type="hidden" value ="1"/>
<a class="class1">Click 1</a>
</div>
<div id="div2">
<input type="hidden" value ="2"/>
<a class="class1">Click 2</a>
</div>
```

And now i want to have a selector listen for one of the anchors to be clicked.

```
$('.class1').click(function(){
var hidVal = $(this).prev().val();
AlerthiddenVal(hidVal);
});
```

And a simple function to alert whats been clicked

```
function AlerthiddenVal(val){
alert(val);
}
```

Now all of this works fine the first time, the second time I run it, it runs the function once with the value of the first click, and then another time with the correct value, this goes on and on as i click more anchor tags. can anyone help me fix this issue, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happen when you bind the function more than time 
if you bind this event to class1 twice the function AlerthiddenVal will run twice

The solution is try to bind this event once when the document load only 
OR 
if its necessary to bind it after a many events 
you need to call the unbind function before rebinding() ex:

```
$('.class1').unbind();
$('.class1').click(function(){
var hidVal = $(this).prev().val();
AlerthiddenVal(hidVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.class1').click(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var hidVal = $(this).prev().val();
    AlerthiddenVal(hidVal);
});
```

Notice `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`. I had an issue similar to yours and this solved it.

Comment: no that did not work, the function is still running twice or more.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.class1').click( function(){
  AlerthiddenVal( 
         $("input",$(this).parent() ).val()  
  );
});
```